# How to make JetBrains webstorm know about `element`, `by` in protractor test spec?

Tags: webstorm, protractor

Right now in my Protractor test spec, Webstorm is complaining that all my `element` and `by` are "Unresolvable type or element"

Comment: Could you please make the question a little clearer by giving us a bit more context? A screenshot would be helpful too.

Comment: seems there is no way to do this:( Please vote for [WEB-11090](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11090)

Answer (score 12):

Have you enabled the TypeScript library for angular-protractor?

1. Go to Project Settings > Javascript > Libraries
2. Click Download then select TypeScript community stubs
3. Find angular-protractor then download and install

Hope that helps!  I know it's not native support but next best thing :-)

Answer (score 4):

`angular-protractor` no longer appears on the list of TypeScript community stubs, presumably because protractor is [now officially supported](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/10/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-6957/) within the WebStorm IDE.

So, in order to ger protractor code completion:

1. Install protractor globally: `npm install -g protractor`
2. On WebStorm, go to Project Settings > Javascript > Node.js and NPM, and make sure protractor appears in the package list.
3. On Project Settings > Javascript > Libraries, click the Add... button and point WebStorm to the protractor directory in your global node_modules. In my Mac's case it's `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor`.

Answer (score 2):

[Ron H´s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339077/ron-h) Answer worked for me, but i also had to download and install the following packages from the TypeScript community stubs.

- `selenium-webdriver`
- `jasmine`
- `karma-jasmine`

After that also `by.id()`, `by.className()`, `iit`, `ddescribe`, `toBeTurthy()`,... was recognized.

Comment: would you know what would recognize browser.actions(), .perform() etc.. these were not recognized ever after downloading and installing your list

Comment: @patz downlaod angular-protractor-DefinitelyTyped too

Answer (score 1):

You could localise variable for your scope:

```
var element = protractor.element;
```