# Protractor-CucumberJS: Webstorm does not display autocomplete when type selenium command

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, cucumber, protractor, webstorm

I using Webstorm IDE for protractor Cucumberjs but when i am typing selenium command like `browser.getTitle()`, then there is no autocomplete display.

Is there anything wrong or Do i missing any config for webstorm? And is there IDE can support autocomplete when i using javascript for protractor-cucumber?

Comment: You would get IDE's for auto-completing javascript commands only. There is no particular IDE developed for protractor.

Comment: you need to add some libs like angular-protractor, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27062721/2519073