# WebStorm does not recognize `browser`, `element` etc in Protractor test spec

Tags: jasmine, protractor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Following [Protractor guide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) I wanted to create my first test. While the test works unfortunately JetBrains WebStorm does not recognize all of my variables in given test

[image: WebStorm view]

I have enabled in Libraries/JavaScript:

1. jasmine
2. karma
3. karma-jasmine
4. HTML
5. Node.js Core
6. selenium-webdriver

As seen above Node.js Core library is enabled.

I have also visited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888240/how-to-make-jetbrains-webstorm-know-about-element-by-in-protractor-test-spe) but unfortunately the angular-protractor is no longer available.

What am I missing?

Comment: one import should work, working perfectly in my editor without any configuration

Comment: The screenshot isn't helpful. What does your tsconfig look like? Where is your import statement? Have you actually looked at the Protractor github account? There is a TypeScript example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JS Hint RC. It will work like magic.
You can find this by going to

> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Javascript(select ECMA Script 6) ->Code Quality Tools- >JS Hint - Enable, use config file.

As for config file, save the bellow file, with following name: '.jshintrc'.

Rate the answer as positive if this worked for you!

```
{
  "jasmine": true,
  "mocha": true,
  "esversion":6,
  "loopfunc": true,
  "node": true,
  "globals": {
    "esversion": 6,
    "angular": false,
    "browser": false,
    "inject": false,
    "_": false,
    "driver": false,
    "protractor": false,
    "$": false,
    "$$": false,
    "element": false,
    "by": false,
    "list": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thaks for the answer. Unfortunately the result is still the same.

Comment: Make sure you select JavaScript ES6, in Webstorm config. :) For me it's working like a charm with protractor.

Answer (score 1):

Your editor will understand it if its imported. Elese it will know where to find `browser` ot `by`

Add import statement at top of your file.

```
import {by, element} from 'protractor';
```